# fillna in series with None

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.Series([1,1,1,1, "something", 1]).astype(float).cumsum().fillna(None)
```

I'd like to fill NaNs with None in the series above but it tells:

> ValueError: Must specify a fill 'value' or 'method'.

All the solutions I've found are using a dataframe, but I need specifically on a Serie. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
s=pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([1,1,1,1, "something", 1]),errors='coerce').cumsum()
s.mask(s.isnull(),None)
```

---

```
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4    None
5       5
```

Note: `pd.Series([1,1,1,1, "something", 1]).astype(float).cumsum()` wouldn't work without `errors='coerce` in `pd.to_numeric`. Also `dtype` returned is `dtype: object`